# <Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix on PhoneGap app

Tags: ios, css, cordova, transform

I'm getting this error and obviously it should be related to the transforms I'm using.
I went through this path and cleared all of the transforms, animations, transitions but still seeing this.

I'm working with PhoneGap 2.2 on ios and I'm doing all scale, translate. I'm not putting the whole code here as I currently believe it should be something else effecting, as I removed all the fancy stuff and still getting this error. Might be wrong, might have skipped something and will post if I do find a mistake on my side.

It would be great if someone else had this before, so would save time before spending hours on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really weird, but one thing I did fixed the issue.

I used to have `display: inline-block;` elements and to align them properly I used to do the trick to give the parent `font-size: 0;`, removing this fixed the issue.

Visually there wasn't any problem anyway but now I'm not getting any console errors.